# How to calculate the voltage on this photodiode cathode?

Tags: voltage, diodes, photodiode

[image]

Given these values, what steps to take to calculate the voltage present on the diode cathode?

- V_bias = 100V
- R_s = 700k
- C_d = 1 uF
- Diode dark current = 10 nA
- Diode capacitance = 50 pF

Comment: If \$C_D\$ is actually is electrolytic and installed as indicated, The voltage across the diode will be 0V or very close

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By "voltage" do you mean the operating point? Without knowing the time function of optical power absorbed by the diode and the diode's efficiency, DC is all we got.

So, since this looks like a DC analysis under dark conditions, the capacitors disappear, the op-amp disappears because it's not even connected to the diode now, and the diode is replaced by the dark current source.

So the problem is more or less trivial: there's a voltage source, an equivalent series resistor, and a current source. That's all. The diode drops some voltage by flowing 10nA of dark current across the 710kΩ of series resistance, and that adds up (with proper sign) with the bias voltage. Done.

> Diode capacitance = 50 pF

One only hopes that's the capacitance at 100V of bias applied to the diode, but it doesn't matter in the problem anyway.

Comment: Ah ok, so 10nA across 710k resistor leads to a 0.0071 voltage drop, which leads to 100-0.0071=99.9929V present at the diode cathode?

Comment: @earl, yes, but assuming this is an APD, you will probably want to tune it by several volts one way or the other to get to the correct operating point, so the few mV drop due to the resistor will be irrelevant.